# React Router mount routes from external package

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to develop an app that takes other "apps" as "plugins". This base app would include only basic auth routes and other apps would define their own routes within them.

How can I accomplish this with React? I suppose React Router could have something, but I have not been able to find it.

I come from a Ruby on Rails world where I could have a gem as an engine and on the base app I would just `mount` the engine on a given path. I was looking for something similar to that, such that on my base `App.js` I could simply `import ModuleARoutes from 'module-a'` and somehow insert it into the base app's `<Router>` component like:

```
<Router>
    <ModuleARoutes path="/module_a" />
</Router>
```

Any guidance is much appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Using the answer from @felipe-lanza I had my ModuleA like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Example1 = () => (<div>test 1</div>);
const Example2 = () => (<div>test 2</div>);

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Example1} />
      <Route exact path="/example1" component={Example2} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
export { App as ExampleApp };
```

And on my base app I have

```
import MainStore from './stores/MainStore';
import AuthStore from './stores/AuthStore';

import App from './App';
import ExampleApp from '@module-platform/example';
const stores = { MainStore, AuthStore };
const Routes = () => (
    <Provider { ...stores }>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Login } />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={ App } />
                <PrivateRoute path="/example_app" component={ ExampleApp } />
                <Route component={ NotFound } />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

And now if I navigate to `localhost/example_app` I do get the expected result (a div with "test 1"). However, I would expect that navigating to `localhost/example_app/example_1` would render the div with "test 2", however it still renders "test 1". As a matter of fact, any location with `localhost/example_app` (e.g. `localhost/example_app/asdfasdfa`) will get me the "test 1" div rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, wouldn't that be akin to rendering the child apps below the base app as different routes?

I.e. (inside your index.js):

```
<Router>
  <Route path='/' component={BaseApp}/>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/child-path-1' component={ChildApp1}/>
    <Route path='/child-path-2' component={ChildApp2}/>
    <Route path='/child-path-n' component={ChildAppN}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Then each child app could have its own routes, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's got me half-way there, I believe. I will edit my question with some updates, and would be most grateful if you could help me get all the way =)

Comment: When you are nesting routes like this, paths are not relative. Just add '/example_app/' before the current paths inside ModuleA. This should also prevent Example1 from being rendered in every path. As a side note you probably don't need that <BrowserRouter>.

Comment: Hi @felipe-lanza thanks for the help! I managed to make it and will edit my answer